# In android device When I click back button till go back to home screen why the app is not removed from recent?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-recents

I found from google Docs[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

> If the user continues to press Back, then each activity in the stack
>   is popped off to reveal the previous one, until the user returns to
>   the Home screen (or to whichever activity was running when the task
>   began). When all activities are removed from the stack, the task no
>   longer exists.

When the task is no longer exists why the app is showing in recents.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you click on the back button and go back to your home screen is that your app is only getting minimized(your app is stopped and not destroyed), and this is why in your recent apps you will see your app that only got minimized.

Comment: According to the documentation android will clear the task right.

Comment: Can you send me a link to that part of the documentation?